# vite.meta.env is working locally but not on the AWS EC2 instance

Tags: laravel, environment-variables, vuejs3, vite

There is an environment variable named `VITE_VARIABLE_NAME=ZXC` in the .env file.

Calling vite.meta.env.VITE_VARIABLE_NAME works fine locally, but doesn't work after deploying to an AWS EC2 instance.

I am using Laravel with Vue and Vite.
I tried several methods and searched on internet. But I can't find any solution.
Any answers would be appreciated.